# Dragging/selecting inside SVG in Firefox

Tags: firefox, xhtml, svg

I am making a web-application which uses an inline SVG as its basic UI element. Some of the UI actions include selecting the text in the SVG, and dragging across the SVG. This works in Webkit and Presto, but Gecko refuses to cooperate. When I try to drag across the SVG in Firefox, it initiates a drag action with the whole SVG image. Is there a way to prevent this default behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is described in the following bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=525591

You can fix this by calling preventDefault() on the event.

This really needs to go in an FAQ somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, `preventDefault` in `dragStart` takes care of being able to drag. I still can't select text though. Any ideas?