# svg dragging targets whole <object> instead of mouse-handlers?

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg

I have an external svg that I embed via an  tag. I then use javascript to insert mouse handlers to -s in order to "rotate" them with the mouse. (Just like knobs on a stereo.)

Now, every once in a while, this doesn't work. Firefox then doesn't show the drag-cursor which I told it to show but instead the crossed-out-circle cursor. Also, it doesn't rotate meaning that the javascript is not run. This happens roughly every third time - other times it works great.

To me, it looks like firefox tries to drag the whole svg-object instead of handing the mouse-events over to the javascript and let that do it's magic.

Does that sound familiar to anybody? What could I do?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, short time after, although I had searched the web, I found the answer myself.

This works just like [Dragging/selecting inside SVG in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259622/dragging-selecting-inside-svg-in-firefox).

Let me quote from there:

> This behaviour is described in the following bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=525591
>   You can fix this by calling preventDefault() on the event.
>   This really needs to go in an FAQ somewhere.

I  have nothing to add :-)